# Now getting updated values in java script

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

Below is my code. I am calling this function on On-load and every-time when something get changed on server side.

```
funtion display() {
    var costAmount = 0;
    var minPrice = parseFloat('{!calc.Minimum_Price__c}');
    var passth = parseFloat('{!calc.passth}');
                    alert("minPrice = " + minPrice + ", passth = " + passth);
    <apex:repeat var="costPlan" value="{!calc.Non_Labor_Cost_Details__r}">                  
        if('{!costPlan.Pass_Non_Pass_Thorugh_Cost__c}' == "Non-Billable to client") {
        costAmount = parseFloat((parseFloat('{!costPlan.Cost_Amount_f__c}') + ((minPrice - passThorughCost) != 0 ? 
        (parseFloat('{!costPlan.Cost_Amount_f__c}') / (minPrice - passThorughCost) *  
        Discount) : 0)));
        } else {
        costAmount = parseFloat('{!costPlan.Cost_Amount_f__c}');
        }
    </apex:repeat>
}
```

Everything is working fine on onload but when i call is after change then still it displays old value. i am not getting updated values.

I check at server side that object it getting updated with latest values but still it displayes old value.

Any suggestions

Thanks

Everything is working fine on onload but when i call is after change then still it displays old value. i am not getting updated values.

I check at server side that object it getting updated with latest values but still it displayes old value.

Any suggestions

Thanks

Comment: When you say after change do you mean a rerender action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping the `<apex:repeat>` in a `<apex:outputPanel>` and using a `rerender` event when you change something on the server side, and use an `<apex:actionFunction>` to

Better yet, replace it with an `@RemoteAction` or `Webservice` annotated method on the controller to get new data from the server.

Both of the web-service style solutions have their benefits and drawbacks, such as maintaining the controller in a certain `state` versus being `stateless`

```
<apex:page>
<apex:actionFunction action="{!controllerAction}" rerender="{!mypanel}" />
<apex:outputPanel id="mypanel">
<apex:repeat var="costPlan" value="{!calc.Non_Labor_Cost_Details__r}">                  
        if('{!costPlan.Pass_Non_Pass_Thorugh_Cost__c}' == "Non-Billable to client") {
        costAmount = parseFloat((parseFloat('{!costPlan.Cost_Amount_f__c}') + ((minPrice - passThorughCost) != 0 ? 
        (parseFloat('{!costPlan.Cost_Amount_f__c}') / (minPrice - passThorughCost) *  
        Discount) : 0)));
        } else {
        costAmount = parseFloat('{!costPlan.Cost_Amount_f__c}');
        }
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Beat me to it! You should elaborate on the state v. stateless part of your answer and make this a wiki.

Comment: i am writing this function in under javascript means<script> </script> tags. will it work?

Comment: After putting <apex:outputPanel> i am getting java script exception - "Uncaught Syntax Error - Unexpected Token < "

Comment: Yes you are correct that if i refresh the page it get resolved. As i am getting exception while applying <apex:outputPanel> in java script so refreshing entire form and issue is resolved. Good Catch :) Thanks a lot